# Duplicated root mount point

Tags: mount, automounting, root-filesystem

I'm using a dual boot computer with Mint and Arch Linux, both sharing some home sub-directories via symbolic link, the link was point to `/mnt/shared` where I mounted a partition.

Everything was working fine until I installed Windows 10 and fixed the grub.. Now suddenly the Mint is mounting the root partition onto `/mnt/shared` and `/`. I can't find any reason why this is happening and I was unable fix the problem either.

Edit: /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=fbf984a3-ec69-4d8b-8399-0389186a45b8 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=0A5B-DF1A  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sda2 /mnt/shared auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a5d63888-9c0c-4b6b-95d3-75f2508bc685 /mnt/shared-hd auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Now I see that `/dev/sda2` (root partition) is automatically mounted under `/mnt/shared`.

Comment: Could you add to your question the content of `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: I added it. As I used gnome disk utility to change the mounting points I was unaware of the existence of record in `/etc/fstab`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the symlink, you can add a line like this in the /etc/fstab of each system:

```
/dev/sda2 /home auto defaults,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

Though it's better to use the UID for the partition, so that the mount works even if the layout changes:

```
$ sudo blkid
```

And then in `/etc/fstab`, instead of `/dev/sda2` you write the UID, so you end up with something like this:

```
UUID=0c7...9 /dev/sda2 /home auto defaults,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

Comment: Actually is not the entire home directory that is shared between the distros but only some of their subdirectories such as Documents, Downloads, Pictures and others. So the symbolic link was a viable solution for me. I didn't share the entire home directory because some config files can conflict between distros.